# Reveal.js Keyboard Binding Not Working

Tags: javascript, reveal.js

I am trying to set the keyboard binding in Reveal.js but it isn't working. I was following these instructions: https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js/#keyboard-bindings

This is the code:

```
Reveal.configure({
  keyboard: {
    37: 'next',
    65: function() { alert("Hello"); },
    66: null
  }
});
```

Did I do something wrong? If so, how can I fix it?

Comment: Try adding these configurations in `Reveal.initialize()` vs `Reveal.configure()`?

Comment: Good idea. I tried that but it still doesn't work.